# Recoding a variable in R with missing values

Tags: r

I'm having difficulty understanding why my code to create a dummy variable isn't working. My `data` contains some `NA` values and is of the following form:

```
Year   Month   Var1  Var2
2006    9      278   345
2006    10     251   857
2006    11     254   678
.      .       .     . 
.      .       .     .
2015   12      230   641
2016    1      647    268
2016    2      NA    785
2016    3      NA    419
.      .       .     . 
.      .       .     .
2016   6      NA     369
```

I'm trying to create a seasonal additive dummy variable that will equal one for December starting in 2014 and continuing on. I can't understand why the following code doesn't work.

```
SAout <- ifelse(data$Year<= 2014 & data$Month == 12, 1, 0)
```

For any time after Jan 2016 `SAout` takes the value `NA` which makes no sense to me since `data$Year` is still greater than `2014`.

```
SAout
[1]  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
 [41]  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
 [81]  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0 NA NA NA NA NA NA
```

**EDIT**

I can create the variable I want with the following

```
data$SAout <- ifelse(data$Year >= 2014 & data$Month == 12, 1, 0)
data$SAout[is.na(data$SAout)]<-0
```

However I don't understand why the second line of code should be necessary.

Comment: Your logical statement doesn't reflect what you say you want. You want something like `ifelse(data$Year >= 2014 & data$Month == 12, 1, 0)`.

Comment: That's the exact code I have written above. Isn't it?

Comment: I had a typo, sorry. But that is the same code I was using that is giving NA's

Comment: I can't reproduce this myself.  Are you absolutely sure there are no `NA`s in your month column?  In R logic, `TRUE & NA` returns `NA`, and `ifelse(NA, ...)` will also return `NA`.

Comment: I did have a problem with the way my data was pulled in. Once I changed that the code runs fine. Thanks, sorry about the confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its be because you are trying to create a dummy variable with 2 conditions.

1. data$year > 2013
2. data$month == 12

In your code it says if year and month is equal to 12.

Rather try the following code

```
data$SAout<-ifelse(data$year >=2014 & data$month==12,1,0)
```

Comment: Sorry I had a typo in my question. That is the same conditional logic I had written but for Feb. 2016 on I'm getting NA's instead of 0's

Comment: Perhaps make sure your data is a numeric...`data$year<-as.numeric(data$year)`?

Comment: Yea data$Year and data$Month are both numeric

Comment: Sorry, but without seeing the whole dataset, the cause will remain a mystery. There are workarounds if needs be... for instance, you can use `library(lubridate)` to create a sequence of date by month, use `year()` and `month()` to recreate your date columns in `data` and then create your dummy. Like I said, not ideal, but could be possible workaround if you need it